# Do people say じゅういち　or　いちいち when saying 11?

Tags: word-choice, numbers

I heard this sentence. 仕事はひまでしたが、うちでよるいちいちまでレポートを書いています。

I looked up いちいち and it could mean `11` or `one-by-one` or `separately`. I'm guessing this in sentence it's saying 11. However, I'm wondering if いちいち normal for saying 11.

Comment: Are you sure what you heard wasn't this いちいち http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/12307/m0u/ ? いちいちまでdoesn't make much sense.

Comment: Is there any possibility that it was よるいちじまで?

Comment: @Chocolate You might be right. It sounded like `いちち` when I heard it the first (few) times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it wrong. Even if it meant `11`, I would then ask you "11 what?". `11まで` does not mean much.

I have not met any cases where it means `11`. If I check it out, there is [nothing about it](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/13938/m0u/).

Comment: This is where I found it from: [ichi ichi made](http://www.worldcat.org/title/sekai-o-yurugashita-junen-berurin-no-kabe-hokai-kara-kyu-ichiichi-made/oclc/170068156)

Comment: @snailplane I think this is just a human mistake.

Comment: @dotnetN00b, that's just part of a fixed way to say 9.11. It's not pronounced like that generally (I think I've heard it used for 3.11 as well).

Comment: @dainichi I believe that Chocolate, you, and oldergod have it right. Now if there were some way to combine your comments as one answer, I'd mark that correct. For now, I'll mark this as the answer.